# failedPrecondition error when fetching nextMessages from gmail using history ID - Google API

Tags: java, google-api, gmail-api, google-api-java-client

I am trying to fetch new email messages based on history ID from my gmail mailbox. I do authentication using OAuth. I am got Bad Request Exception with reason as failedPrecondition.  but I can't figure out what I need to do here.

Reference - [History.list](https://developers.google.com/gmail/api/v1/reference/users/history/list)

Here is the piece of code getting bad Request Exception.  Can someone help me on this issue.

```
    try {
          History.List listRequest =
              this.gmail
                  .users()
                  .history()
                  .list(userId)
                  .setMaxResults(SYNC_PAGE_SIZE)
                  .setStartHistoryId(new BigInteger(historyId))
                  .setHistoryTypes(Collections.singletonList(MESSAGE_ADDED_EVENT));
          if (response != null) {
            listRequest.setPageToken(((GmailPartialSyncResponse) response).getNextPageToken());
          }

          return new GmailPartialSyncResponse(listRequest.execute());
```

I am getting the Bad RequestException with reason as 'failedPrecondition' as below,

> Exception Details:
>           {
>             "detailMessage": "myProject.exception.EmailMessageException: Failed to fetch emails on partial sync.",
>             "cause": {
>               "detailMessage": "Failed to fetch emails on partial sync.",
>               "cause": {
>                 "statusCode": 400,
>                 "statusMessage": "Bad Request",
>                 "content": "{\n  \"code\" : 400,\n  \"errors\" : [ {\n    \"domain\" : \"global\",\n    \"message\" : \"Bad Request\",\n    \"reason\" : \"failedPrecondition\"\n  } ],\n  \"message\" : \"Bad Request\"\n}",
>                 "detailMessage": "400 Bad Request\n{\n  \"code\" : 400,\n  \"errors\" : [ {\n    \"domain\" : \"global\",\n    \"message\" : \"Bad Request\",\n    \"reason\" : \"failedPrecondition\"\n  } ],\n  \"message\" : \"Bad Request\"\n}",
>                 "stackTrace": [
>                   {
>                     "declaringClass": "com.google.api.client.googleapis.json.GoogleJsonResponseException",
>                     "methodName": "from",
>                     "fileName": "GoogleJsonResponseException.java",
>                     "lineNumber": 146
>                   },
>                   {
>                     "declaringClass": "com.google.api.client.googleapis.services.json.AbstractGoogleJsonClientRequest",
>                     "methodName": "newExceptionOnError",
>                     "fileName": "AbstractGoogleJsonClientRequest.java",
>                     "lineNumber": 113
>                   },
>                   {
>                     "declaringClass": "com.google.api.client.googleapis.services.json.AbstractGoogleJsonClientRequest",
>                     "methodName": "newExceptionOnError",
>                     "fileName": "AbstractGoogleJsonClientRequest.java",
>                     "lineNumber": 40
>                   },
>                   {
>                     "declaringClass": "com.google.api.client.googleapis.services.AbstractGoogleClientRequest$1",
>                     "methodName": "interceptResponse",
>                     "fileName": "AbstractGoogleClientRequest.java",
>                     "lineNumber": 321
>                   },
>                   {
>                     "declaringClass": "com.google.api.client.http.HttpRequest",
>                     "methodName": "execute",
>                     "fileName": "HttpRequest.java",
>                     "li...

Comment: Please edit your question and include the rest of your code we need to see how you are authenticateing for starters.

Comment: Are you using a regular account or a Service Account? Could you share the code related to the authentication steps?

Answer (score 0):

You should probaby follow the [Java quickstart.](https://developers.google.com/gmail/api/quickstart/java)

## Create service

```
Gmail service = new Gmail.Builder(HTTP_TRANSPORT, JSON_FACTORY, getCredentials(HTTP_TRANSPORT))
            .setApplicationName(APPLICATION_NAME)
            .build();
```

## List History.

```
 public static void listHistory(Gmail service, String userId, BigInteger startHistoryId)
      throws IOException {
    List<History> histories = new ArrayList<History>();
    ListHistoryResponse response = service.users().history().list(userId)
        .setStartHistoryId(startHistoryId).execute();
    while (response.getHistory() != null) {
      histories.addAll(response.getHistory());
      if (response.getNextPageToken() != null) {
        String pageToken = response.getNextPageToken();
        response = service.users().history().list(userId).setPageToken(pageToken)
            .setStartHistoryId(startHistoryId).execute();
      } else {
        break;
      }
    }

    for (History history : histories) {
      System.out.println(history.toPrettyString());
    }
  }
```